# last modified date of file in Qt resource system

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.3, qfileinfo

Normally you can get last modified date easily with QFileInfo::lastModified().
However this doesn't work when a file inside Qt's resource system is used

```
QFileInfo resourceInfo("://resource.txt");
qDebug() << resourceInfo.lastModified().toString() // returns ""
```

Is there a possibility to find out the last modified date without temporarily copying the file from the resources to the file system?

Comment: Have you tried using a single `/`?, `QFileInfo resourceInfo(":/resource.txt");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add a file to a resource, it's compiled into the final executable binary, so there is no concept of a file as there is in the filesystem, which is why lastModified doesn't return a value.

Comment: Ah I get the concept now. I'm using the last modified date of the binary itself.